# How to change the height of a Ext.ProgressBar

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs4.1

I have a simple `Ext.ProgressBar` and need to double it's height which works but didn't scale the progress image, just the outer box. I thought OK, maybee it is to small and can't scale but it has a height of >800px (sencha original images).

So how can this be done?

Here's the config

```
{
    xtype: 'progressbar',
    text: 'Some text',
    border: 1,
    height: 40
}
```

Comment: How are you currently doubling the height? sounds like you might have just hit the wrong dom element

Comment: @dougajmcdonald See my edit. I also looked at the DOM and found out that there are two overlaping elements. But I thought ExtJS manages the height and not that I need to manipulate on the DOM...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Height of progress bar is set in style definition. You can change height by changing `.x-progress-bar` css class. In modern browsers (eg. Chrome) all you need to do is to change `height` property, because background image is definied as gradient. Example:

```
// height of bar
.x-progress-bar {
    height: 38px;
}
// height of text box
.x-progress-text {
    height: 38px;
    line-height: 38px;
}
```

Working sample: http://jsfiddle.net/D2QYN/2/

Another way is to attach handler to `render` event and set `height` of child elements which are not scaled verically. Example handler:

```
listeners: {
    render: function(sender) {
        var height = sender.bar.parent().getHeight(true); // content height
        sender.bar.setStyle('height', height + 'px');
        sender.textEl.setStyle('height', height + 'px');
        sender.textEl.setStyle('line-height', height + 'px');
    }
}
```

Working sample: http://jsfiddle.net/D2QYN/3/

Comment: Thanks for the answer and the example! But I have 6 differents height values. (the design guys...) So that isn't really an option for me :(

Comment: I've added second solution. See my answer.